# Set list property value using LINQ ForEach

Tags: c#, linq

I am using below linq query to set value of SecKey, but I still see the old value in list studentData,

below id the sample I am using which is not working/not setting the value,

```
studentData.Where(w => w.ActiveDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.ActiveDate.Date) && w.EndDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.EndDate.Date)).ToList().ForEach(s => s.SecKey = secKey);
```

Here I made up some data,

```
public struct Student
{
    public string BadgeNum;
    public DateTime ActiveDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public decimal Amount;
    public decimal? SecKey;
}


List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

students.Add(new Student() {
 BadgeNum = "1"
 ,
 ActiveDate = new DateTime(2014,4,4)
 ,
 EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 6)
 ,
 Amount = 10
 ,
 SecKey = 1
});

students.Add(new Student()
{
    BadgeNum = "1"
    ,
    ActiveDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 6)
    ,
    EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 9)
    ,
    Amount = 10
    ,
    SecKey = 1
});

students.Add(new Student()
{
    BadgeNum = "1"
    ,
    ActiveDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 9)
    ,
    EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 6, 6)
    ,
    Amount = 10
    ,
    SecKey = 1
});

foreach (var b in students)
{

    if (b.ActiveDate.Date.Equals(new DateTime(2014, 5, 9)) && b.EndDate.Date.Equals(new DateTime(2014, 6, 6)))
    {
        b.SecKey = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ has no `ForEach` method.

Comment: In what way is your code "not working".

Comment: @Servy it is not setting the value of SecKey. What is your solution to this?

Comment: Yes, it *is* setting the value of `SecKey`.  You'll need to demonstrate in more detail what you're doing, what's happening, and what you expect to happen, if you want to get a working solution.  As it is, there isn't enough information to know what the problem is.

Comment: One question coming to mind... Why is Student a struct and not a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to achieve your goal without creating a new list, try this:

```
foreach (var student in studentData.Where(w => w.ActiveDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.ActiveDate.Date) && w.EndDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.EndDate.Date)))
{
student.SecKey = secKey;
}
```

edit: this was created under the assumption that student is a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: I don't think it works, Cannot modify members of 'student' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: @CoolArchTek You most certainly can.  You cannot modify the value of the variable (well, you could, but it wouldn't do anything useful), but you can modify the object that that variable references, which is what its doing.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mutable value type, thus when you're iterating over the collection you're copying all of the items and mutating that copy, leaving the value in the list unchanged.

If you want to continue to use a value type here, you'll need to assign the mutated value back to the corresponding position in the list.

Really though, you shouldn't be using a value type here at all, and mutable value types in particular should be avoided, partly for reasons such as this case here where you end up unknowingly mutating a copy of the value you intended to change.  The preferable solution would be to simply change the type to be a `class` instead.

Comment: If we are talking about OP's original answer, it will not be enough to change Student to class. Because, he has called ToList() and he was changing values in that list.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Yes, it would be enough.  If the type were a reference type then he would be mutating the objects that the references pointed to, and since the original list would still have the same references to the mutated objects, the result would be the items in the original list having the mutated values.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do ToList in query it will return new list.

```
var newlist = studentData.Where(w => w.ActiveDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.ActiveDate.Date) && w.EndDate.Date.Equals(otherObject.EndDate.Date)).ToList();

newlist.ForEach(s => s.SecKey = secKey);
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer ? Even I provided before other.

Comment: This answer is no different than the code in the OP with respect to the functionality in question.